# Preventing device from accessing open WiFi networks

Tags: wi-fi

How can I prevent my son from accessing open WiFi networks that do not require a passcode? I have my router restricted for adult content and I have my mobile provider set to restrict porn sites. But open WiFi networks are everywhere, and there is no way to prevent him from accessing these sites on other networks.  Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible unless you restrict access to the device's Wifi itself, which is not possible on current most popular OS's(not without unofficial modification atleast) Android, iOS and Windows Phone.

There are apps that can control accessibility of porn websites(Apple has its own) on the device itself(thus it will deny requests to porn websites from the router), but if your kids really want to, there's always a way around the filter.

Maybe it's time to think that censorship isn't a modern solution to these kind of things anymore.